# How to make the jar file executing after being double clicked

Tags: java

I have the next problem - my .jar file works when I invoke it from the command line as java -jar name.jar
But it does not start when I double click on it on the desktop of my Windows 7...
Moreover, when I try to start it with clicking the right buttonof the mouse "open with" and choose Java(TM) SE platform binary it does not start either
How to make it start with the double click?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the `.jar` extension is not associated with `javaw.exe` on your computer.

To do this, run the following two commands in a commandline window:

```
ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
assoc .jar jarfile
```

(Adjust the path to javaw.exe to your installation path)

You should run this with an account that has administrative privileges as this will update the globel registry.

Edit (after the comments):
As Java7 is not yet that widespread, you should re-compile your sources using the compiler switch `-target 1.6` or compile them using Java6 right from the start. The your jar file should also with Java6

Comment: I did that but the problem persists. When I start the program with the double click - the command window will appear for half of second so I cannot see what is written there - something that the "system could not find or load the main class "absolute path here"...Bit it is strange because the jar definitely runs from cmd and has manifest with main-class: Program \n

Comment: If the commandline window appears, then you linked the jarfiles to java.exe not javaw.exe. Does your jar file need other jar files? Maybe there is a problem with the full classpath specified in your manifest.

Comment: No, there are no other jars in my jar...in the manifest there is only Main-Class: users.metropolia.Program - this is the things specified there nothing else...

Comment: The question is not if there are other jars **in** your jar (which doesn't work anyway), the question is: does it **need** other libraries?

Comment: No, no other libraries except the original javax.swing, javax.awt and java.util

Comment: You can actually download the whole jar at users.metropolia.fi/~artemm

Comment: It is there with the source files in src folder

Comment: The class files are compiled with Java7. Most probably your .jar file association links to a Java6 installation which cannot run Java7 compiled classes.

Comment: actually I have 2 jre`s on my computer - jre 6 and jre 7...I bound the jarfile to both javaw.exe - no result still...

Comment: No it doesn't because I have linked jarfiles to a Java6 installation. I guess when you run `java -jar` it's using your Java7 installation

Comment: I have uninstalled jre6 abd rewrote jarfile path with assoc...Nothing helped